# Show corresponding dash line on x-axis and y-axis in R base plot and GGPlot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need to show corresponding dash line of the data points on x-axis and y-axis, and the corresponding (x,y) coordinates near the respective data points on the graph. I need to do this in base R plot and GGPlot2 respectively.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: Hi mochalatte, I'm a little confused by what you're asking for. Can you possible draw up an example? I can't tell whether you're asking for a blank plot with "+" characters for the data points or whether you'd like something like a dash in the plot margin at the x and y coords of each data point

Comment: Please add data using `dput` or something that we can copy and use. Read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: @Dubukay Thanks for your attention. I can't draw the graph now, but I need something like dash line starts from the data point of graph to the respective axis, and show the corresponding value near the data point in (x, y) form.

Comment: @RonakShah Understood. Will try to follow the rules. But I'm not authorize to release the data, may need to modify it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for something like this:

```r
dat <- data.frame(x=1:10, y=1:10)
```

Base R:

```r
plot(dat$x, dat$y, axes=F, xlab="", ylab="", type="n")
segments(x0 = dat$x, x1 = dat$x, y0 = 0, y1 = dat$y, lty = 2)
segments(x0 = 0, x1 = dat$x, y0 = dat$y, y1 = dat$y, lty = 2)
text(paste0(dat$x, ", ", dat$y), x=dat$x+0.2, y=dat$y+0.2)
```

[image]

ggplot2:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = dat) +
  geom_segment(aes(x=x, xend=x, y=0, yend=y), lty=2) +
  geom_segment(aes(x=0, xend=x, y=y, yend=y), lty=2) +
  geom_text(aes(x=x, y=y, label=paste0(x, ", ", y)), nudge_x = 0.1, nudge_y = 0.1) +
  theme_void()
```

[image]